# How to install dictionaries in Excalibur?

Tags: mactex, dictionaries, spanish

When installing MacTeX it comes with a LaTeX spell checker, [Excalibur](http://excalibur.sourceforge.net/). The [homepage](http://excalibur.sourceforge.net/) has links to download dictionaries in different languages: I'm interested in the Spanish one. My problem is that Excalibur doesn't recognize it as a dictionary. Does anyone have an idea about how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Perhaps you could explain what you did: for example, where did you place the dictionary file(s)?

Comment: Hi, I placed the dictionary file in /Applications/TeX/Excalibur-4.0.7, where the standard dictionary (which does work) is.

Comment: You need to open the dictionary in Excalibur: see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

For me, everything seems to work. I did the following:

1. [Downloaded Excalibur](http://excalibur.sourceforge.net/downloads.html)
2. Mounted the disk image and copied all of the files into a new folder (I did this on my Desktop, but anywhere would do)
3. Downloaded the [Spanish dictionary](http://excalibur.sourceforge.net/dict/spanish.zip)
4. Unzipped the dictionary and copied it into the Excalibur folder
5. Started Excalibur and used Dictionary, Open Dictionary ... to open the Spanish dictionary

Provided you copy the dictionary to the Excalibur folder and then make Excalibur aware of it, it seems to find the dictionary the next time you start the program.

Comment: You may need to close and restart Excalibur if it was running when you installed the dictionary.

Comment: I did the same, but when I'm in step 5 I cannot select the spanish dictionary (it appears in gray in the 'Chose a File' window).

Comment: @MonicaG I've never installed Excalibur before, and the steps above are exactly what I did with the latest version. Alan tells me (in chat) that he was successful and did not even need to Open the dictionary as he copied it while Excalibur was closed.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is your OS X version?

Comment: @MonicaG 10.8.3

Comment: Well I'll keep trying to install it, thanks. I have OS X 10.7.5 and I've read it comes with some missing libraries, perhaps there is where my problem lies.

Comment: Maybe, try download the dictionary and/or Excalibur again? :/